# make ArrayList According to result dart/flutter?

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, dart

"ProductDetails":
"

```
x:x:SBRNDxxxxxxxxxx08101:SPRODxxxxxxxxx065002:6000:5:6300:5.25:8400:7:2:2:o:0:0; // tea
x:x:SBRNDxxxxxxxxxx02801:SPRODxxxxxxxxx028510:156:13:168:14:240:20:3:3:o:0:0; // water
```

how to make ArrayList according to above result.

Comment: "how to make ArrayList according to above result" is a really confusing question. What are you trying to do here ? One could create a thousand different valid results to the question. Try and be more specific.

Comment: What do you mean by `making an ArrayList from the result`? What is the type of the elements,  is the `result` a list of strings that needs to be parsed to objects?